# Regex to match non preceding character and matching following character

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to understand why the following regex is not working. My requirement is as below.

Match "config" that is not followed by . (period). For those that match, "config" should not be preceded by *. Also, this should be the function params meaning it should be between ( and ). Following is what I have and it doesn't give me correct values. This is in Java.

```
String condition1 = "config.property == function(/*config ConfigCon */config,\"\")";
String condition2 = "config.property == function(/*config ConfigCon */config.prop1,\"\")";
String key = "config";
String matchString = "\\(.*(?<!\\*)" + key + "(?!\\.).*\\)";
System.out.println(matchString);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(matchString);
Matcher m = p.matcher(condition1);
//The below should say true;
boolean cond = m.find();
//The below should say false;
m = p.matcher(condition2);
cond = m.find();
```

My logic is start with escaped ( followed by one or more chars, Negative Lookbehind for escaped * followed by key followed by Negative Lookahead for esscaped . followed by one ore more chars followed by escaped ). What am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `\\` from regex start and end it will work. Use regex `(.*(?<!\\*)" + key + "(?!\\.).*)`.

I tried this it was giving `true` for first and `false` for second.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also need them to be between the parantheses. As I noted above, I had the regex right but had a typo in the condition1 which caused the issue.

Comment: @Karthik so you solved the issue or it yet to be solved??

Comment: If you want to include parentheses also use `(\\(.*(?<!\\*)" + key + "(?!\\.).*\\))`

Comment: it is now resolved, thank you for your reply, I was using the regex right and it had a typo. I updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responses. I had a typo in condition1 where I was giving confi instead of config towards the end. The regex I had was correct initially but I had to spend lot of time debugging because of typo !! It is there for any one to use if they need this kind of functionality